# pagespeed FCP value : why doesn't it take the lab value?

Tags: google-pagespeed, lighthouse

Why do we always have TWO separate FCP values on all pagespeed report please?

On many sites I'm optimizing all these pages have a FCP way under 3s but are still viewed by Google PageSpeed as with a FCP > 3s !

In the pagespeed page the first FCP measure (> 3s) seems to come from a lighthouse cache while the lab measure (1 s or so) seems to be the real one

Can someone explain why Google PageSpeed takes the "cached" value and not the lab value ??

Thanks

Cyril

Comment: the value you are talking about is the real world performance measured by end users within their browser. Care to share your URL in the comments so I can take a look for you?

Comment: Hi, Thanks : here are some example please : https://www.pulsar-informatique.com/service-seo/1841-qu-est-ce-que-l-optimisation-seo

https://www.pulsar-informatique.com/creation-site-internet/comment-creer-un-site-internet

or

https://www.pulsar-informatique.com/actus-blog/entry/office-365-business-model thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood what the two sets of data mean.

The FCP **field data** is gathered from real users, it uses their browser to see how long it takes for FCP.

The **lab test** is simulated. It takes a connection, applies throttling to simulate 4G conditions (latency, throughput speed) as well as reduced CPU performance and then returns a 'best guess' as to the speed of your site.

Because of this it is only a simulated guess as to how your site behaves (albeit reasonably accurate).

Also the FCP field data is split into sections - green is less than 1 second, orange is 1 to 3 seconds and red is greater than 3 seconds.

**So for your site:-**

2% of users get less than one second FCP.

63% of users get a FCP between 1 second and 3 seconds

35% of users get a FCP greater than 3 seconds.

As the simulate test shows a FCP of 1.6 seconds when I run it that is why majority of your users are in the yellow.

The scores in field data are on a rolling 30 day period as well so if you have only just made improvements to your page performance it will take 30 days to give an accurate picture.

What you also have to consider is your visitors may be on 3G not 4G, they may have a cheap phone that is slower than the lab test, the routing to a CDN (if you use one) may be different for your actual users vs Google's server etc. etc.

**The field data is far more accurate and should be what you use to assess your site performance, the lab data is a guide.**

One other thing I noticed that may explain the wide array of FCP times is when I ran the test a few times I got between a 500ms FCP and a 1.7s FCP (due to Time To First Byte being as high as 1 second) - this points to your hosting not being up to par or that your database is slow (so cache your pages).

### Golden rule with PSI

Remember PSI is a diagnostic tool, follow the guidance on what to fix and your site will be as fast as it can be, don't focus too much on the score just make sure you pass all the diagnostics and you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to follow your advice